# Spring MVC sending message codes from controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, localization

I'm working with Spring MVC and i would like to know how to send a message code from controller, which can then be converted in the proper internationalized message in the view.

I.E.
Now I have:
- in controller

```
  model.addAttribute("pgName","fileList.pgName");
```

- in view

  ```
      <h1 class="leftTitle"><s:message code="${pgName}" /></h1>
  ```

This prints the string

> fileList.pgName

. 
I would like it to print the content of the localized string matching fileList.pgName.

Please note that I prefer not have to use something like

```
    String pageName = messageSource.getMessage("fileList.pgName", locale);
```

Because I would have to fill the locale in all my controllers, instead I want them "locale-agnostic".

Comment: What view technology are you using? JSP, Thymeleaf, and maybe others have this functionality built into the view engine itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<spring:message code="${pgName}"/>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have in the view (I'm sorry for a mistake the view code didn't appear in my question, now it's shown). It prints the string

                   fileList.pgName

Comment: @Massimo do you have this value fileList.pgName in resource bundle?